# Problems with Creating Bar Plot In R

Tags: r

[Image of Problematic Barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp9KW.png)

Hello everyone, this is my first time posting on Stack Exchange and I will start off by saying that I am a beginner at coding, (like, really a beginner).

I am having issues creating a barplot for one of my classes. (I have attached an image of this problematic barplot in this post).

As you will be able to see, there are two problems with it:

(1) The legend practically blocks out the whole fourth plot

and

(2) I just can't get there to be one color per leaf shape, (there are multiple leaf shapes represented by one color, in other words. I have 13 leaf shapes, I would like 13 different colors, one per shape).

Lastly, here is the code I used to generate the plot:

```
barplot(shape_biome_table,beside=T,legend.text = T,col=c(1:13), 
      main="Leaf Shapes By Biome Type",
      xlab="Leaf Shape",ylab="Frequency",las=1,
      args.legend=list(x="topright"))
```

If someone can please help me in figuring out what needs to be done to solve these two issues I would be very appreciative. And, as I mentioned previously, I am not very well versed in coding jargon, so please try to make your explanation as easy as possible to understand.

Thank you very much!

Comment: For the color, try `col=rainbow(13)`

Comment: G5W, thank you very much for that, it is much better than what it used to be! Although all of the colors are different, some of them are still quite close in shade to one another, potentially making it challenging for others to discern between them. Is there any way to make the 13 colors really stand out from each other, (I really don't mind typing out all 13 colors if I need to, I just need to know how to type them). Thank you!

Comment: You can use a list of 13 distinct colors either giving them by name - something like `col=c("skyblue", "darkred", … (11 more))`.  You can get the available color names by typing `colors()`.  OR you can specify RGB values `col=c("#880000", "#2222AA", …)`

Answer (score 0):

R's native plotting support is a bit cumbersome. Perhaps the first thing is to try [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/). I've tried to make a guess at what your data looks like.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

shape_biome_table <- tribble(
~leaf.shape, ~biome,
"Acicular", "Hawaiian Natives",
"Acicular", "Hawaiian Natives",
"Acuminate", "Hawaiian Natives",
"Aristate", "Mediterranean" )

ggplot(shape_biome_table, aes(x = leaf.shape, fill = leaf.shape)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ biome)
```